# Handling **** OSType in a Cocoa NSDocument application

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I have written an editor that I would like to be able to handle any file, including those with no extension.

I think that I need to add `****` to the Document OS Types in my filetype entry in the Info.plist, but whereas this does allow me to drag any file to the dock icon, it doesn't attempt to open the file with the associated `NSDocument` class, instead telling me that my application doesn't know how to open the "SimpleText Format" format.

Any help with the step I have missed here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom `NSDocumentController` subclass and override the `typeForContentsOfURL:error:` method, returning the name of a document type, specified by `CFBundleTypeName` in the application’s `Info.plist` file

In order to make the application use your custom `NSDocumentController`, just drag a generic object into your `MainMenu.xib` file and assign it your document controller's class. The document architecture will then automatically use your document controller subclass instead of a generic `NSDocumentController`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this eventually by creating a second document type linked to the same nsdocument subclass with * in the extensions box.